# Bash: Retrive value inside an element tag

Tags: bash

I'm stuck with developing within my bash script (policies...).
I'm having a hard time finding a way to retrieve an value within the XML element variable itself. I've tried multiple ways but would appreciate any suggestions.
Bash only (or I can solve it myself..).

Example:

```
<Timestamp q="2016-09-26T10:03:53Z"/>
```

Do not confuse this with

```
<Timestamp>
2016-09-26T10:03:53Z
</Timestamp>
```

Cheers.

Comment: Provide your complete `XML` file and your expected output.

Comment: Sorry I cannot provide my XML file. I've given an example which is everything that's needed for this particular question.

Comment: Need to know how far the root node is and what  sub level is the node you are expecting is present at?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Example="1" Version="1">
 <Example1 q="EX1"/>
 <Example2 q="EX2"/>
 <Timestamp q="2016-09-26T10:03:53Z"/>
</Example>

Comment: @codex: That's not XML.

Comment: @codex: Tag name can't contain `="1"`.

Comment: @choroba I've anonymized it for this purpose, focus on the task next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by:
grep -o 'Timestamp .............'

Answer (score 0):

Use an XML aware tool like `xmllint`:

```
xmllint --xpath 'string(//Timestamp/@q)' file.xml
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer but I can't use xmllint or else I would've probably gone with that approach.